# How do I forward a TCP connection to WebSockets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, websocket, eventmachine

I have a Rails 3 web application which needs to:

- retrieve a stream data from an external service using a TCP connection
- ensure the user is authorized to view the data (In my rails app I use devise and cancan)
- forward the data to the client using WebSockets.

There could be many clients wanting to look at one stream of data so it would be good if the web app could simply broadcast the stream to the clients.

I've come across following technologies which might be useful:

- [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify)
- [web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js)
- [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket)
- [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki)

I want to know if I'm on the right track, and hear any other advice you have. Perhaps I need to make another Ruby app which runs in parallel to the Rails app?

Comment: So, you want to have the client connect, and you then make an outbound connection to receive data, when the data is received you stream it back to the client?

Comment: Easiest way is to use https://github.com/stevegraham/slanger at the beginning. Personally I like em-websocket for the websocket things, although it's slim, but can be extended better than anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using EventMachine + em-websocket. Peepcode has a few really comprehensive tutorials which helped get me started.